# What to put in a biography for a publication?

Tags: publications

A publication I submitted to said that I need to include a biography in the paper.  I don't have many formal qualifications, aside from my degree.  I have done my research on my own, and am unaffiliated.  What can I put in the biography?

Comment: In my neck of the woods, it is common to list your degrees, relevant work experience/current position, and research interests.

Comment: Keep it simple. "horse hair is a graduate of the University of Southern North Dakota at Hoople and a regular user at Academia StackExchange."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check a few articles of the journal you publish in and look at what other author are putting in their biography.

Mostly it will be about your degrees (BSc, MSc, PhD, when and where), the field of research you are interested in and what is your current occupation. In summary you can state anything that shows your experitise in the subject you are discussing in the paper.

If no one but yourself paid you for the research, you can state it like:

> beside a job as *your paying job* he/she is working on *paper subject*

or

> Since *date* has been working on *paper subject*

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have strong qualifications or your own research history it is best to focus on your interests and goals. Think about these questions:

- What have you done?
- What are you doing now?
- What do you want to do in the future?
- Why is this publication important to you?